# How do I move a chose Node to the front of my LinkedList Queue?

Tags: c++, linked-list, queue

Essentially,

if I had 3 elements a->b->c->d

I want a function that can take a variable, say 'c' and then have it move to the front of the list, so:

OUTPUT:

c->a->b->d

I started off with a helper method that will search for an element through the list.

But I scratched that off, and now I am totally lost and don't know how to start on this!

Here is the search method I had:

```
Node* Queue::search(int val){
Node *head;
Node* chosenNode = head;

while(chosenNode != NULL){
  if(chosenNode->next == val){
     return chosenNode;
   }else{
     chosenNode = chosenNode->next;
   }
 }
}
```

Comment: where is your code ?

Comment: why don't you add a shared variable that holds tail and head? Shared between all cells.

Comment: @Mohsen_Fatemi sorry I added the search code I had, but I don't think that will help :/

Comment: @huseyintugrulbuyukisik so you mean store the tail and the head in a separate shared variable and then change the arrangement on the the nodes the way I like?

Comment: @GowthamMohan for example, when you push/pop a node, it also changes some variable that is accessible from re-order function and maybe by nodes themselves too?.